# Virtual smart card login, revocation status could not be determined

Tags: windows, certificate

We are doing some tests with virtual smart cards and have set up two virtual machines. One server and one client.
The client has been able to connect and receive a smart card certificate from the server but when we try to log in with the smart card icon, after we type in the pin for the card and the client has tried to log in for a while (while saying "welcome") we get this:

```
   The revocation status of the domain controller certificate used for authentication could not be determined.
```

We have searched and searched and have tried to Disable CRL Checking, by following this:
http://www.page-house.com/blog/2009/04/how-to-disable-crl-checking.html
but nothing so far has changed anything.
Neither of the machines have internet access but surely this could work anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure time and date are the same on server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Logon as an admin and Check the software that reads the CAC cert also make sure that the smart card reader is installed properly.